# Matlab Log-Likelihood Threshold

Tags: matlab, math, speech-recognition

I try to implement a speech detection application on matlab. For this purpose;  I try to examine likelihood between speech and wanted word in that speech. I use below code to calculate likelihood :

```
[P, log_like] =posterior(model,speech_frame');
```

model is the acoustic model of wanted word, speech_frame is part of speech could contains many wanted word in it. Anyway, above code returns log_like as 4.969621267039301e+03 or something like. I need to build a threshold for this value. For example, if model and speech is similar as 90%, there is wanted word in that speech. How can I do it ?

DATA:

Frame : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51048269/frame.txt

Model is acquired from : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51048269/model_data.txt
which is represented as below

[image: model]

Comment: Isn't there's a random `.` in your code? What's the format of model and speech_frame? Got some sample data we can test with?

Comment: .' for transpose.. moreover, speech is a recorded speech like 300 mb, so it is divided and processed frame by frame, word is again a recorded sound. Actually you can think like, speech is a sound of a male which taken from a seminar, wanted word is "money". To calculated how many times speaker says money

Comment: in matlab `'` is transpose but what's the random dot?

Comment: I corrected it.. I put it as element-wise

Comment: I see but I still need a sample of the input data to reproduce the issue. Either that or give me a toy example.

Comment: I added sample data..

Comment: I meant more sample data, but I feel this is too high level for me. Perhaps someone else could help. Your could should help anyone giving you an answer though.

Comment: Actually, question is mainly about log-likelihood mathematic.. how can I convert this likelihood values and check whether it is 90% similar or not.

Comment: Oh whoops sorry disregard my previous comment. That was for another question!